# How to prevent Google Chrome from changing the default browser to itself in Windows 7?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, default-settings

I am using Windows 7 (SP1 x64) with Internet Explorer 11. And every time I open Chrome, it makes itself the default browser automatically without my permission. Is Google trying to force me to use its products? I can’t find an option that prevents that in the settings. So I want Internet Explorer to be the default, but I still use Chrome from time to time.

Comment: normally they are asking it. did you change settings or accepted chrome to be your default browser soon after you install it?

Comment: When I used Chrome on other machines before, it always asked me, but on  this PC, it just automatically changes it whenever I open it, I couldn't  find any relevant settings within Chrome, the Default Programs in Control Panel isn't any help either.

Answer (score 3):

1. Download Chrome policies template file (policy_templates.zip)
   https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chrome/policy/policy_templates.zip
   Unzip file from zip file: windows\adm\en-US\chrome.adm
2. Open Local Group Policy Editor
   Run => gpedit.msc => OK.
3. Choose  Computer Configuration/Administrative Template
4. Right click Administrative Template and choose Add/Remove Template.
5. Click Add and choose file chrome.adm that was upzip from policy_templates.zip instep 1 and click Close to close dialog.
6. Choose Computer Configuration/Administrative Template/Classic Administrative Template (ADM)/Google/Google Chrome/
7. Set policy: Set Google Chrome as Default Browser to disabled.
   Now you can check chrome://policy for parameter "DefaultBrowerSettingEnabled" is set to "false".

Answer (score 1):

Another avenue of Attack--

I've had to install Chrome on our office machines to access an EHR that works best on Chrome, but we still need to use Firefox and IE for other websites.

In your case...if Chrome is ALREADY installed and behaving as the Default Browser...

1. FULLY UNINSTALL IT
2. Shutdown and Restart Windows
3. Go to the Browser of your choice that you want to be Default and RESET it     as Default in whichever Settings is needs.
4. If you need to Go to the Chrome Website to Download it afresh WATCH for the CHECKBOX that is ALREADY CHECKED TO MAKE CHROME THE DEFAULT BROWSER...*UNCHECK* IT!!
   *(Better Still-- Hunt/Google for the Off-line Install MSI-- Chrome will Update itself automatically afterwards)*
5. Now INSTALL Chrome again. Except THIS time...when Chrome finishes installing and opens up to the Initial Setup/Login Tabs, turn it off via the hamburger Menu.
6. Now Activate/Open Chrome again.
7. When Chrome Opens for the SECOND time, you will see a Dropdown bar at the top where Chrome ASKS you if you want it to be the DEFAULT Browser. Select **DO NOT ASK AGAIN**

As you now know--Once you Give Chrome Default Status..it doesn't let go of it. The trick is to remember to NEVER give it Default Status from the INITIAL INSTALL.

Now Chrome will remain 'hopefully' subservient to IE or Firefox thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem. After some research, I found that it is caused by a policy named *DefaultBrowserSettingEnabled* that is enabled on my computer.

To check Chrome policies type into the address bar: `chrome://policy`

On my machine I have:

[image: Chrome policy settings image]

Comment: Yes, if you are on a domain, this is another likely cause. Our domain has enabled this policy and it drives me nuts. I want to open shortcuts in IE because it automatically deletes your browsing history, and it also reassociates .html to open in Chrome instead of Notepad++. I haven't found anyway around it. Even if IE is the default like in the answer below, this setting will automatically renable itself. The only thing to do is not use Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Windows
Click the Start button.
Select Default Programs.
Choose the browser you want as your default in the Programs list, and then click Set this program as default.
Click OK.
if it does not works read this page https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/jO2u5l0Xzwg

Comment: Tried that, still not working =( .

Answer (score 0):

Just Make Internet Explorer Default Browser

No matter what version of IE you are using, the Internet Options window is the answer to setting it as your default browser. You would need to go to Tools –> Internet Options, and then to Programs. There you’ll find the button that will set IE as default browser. Click on it, click OK and you’re done!

[image]

Comment: Yes tried that but again, when I open Chrome, it changes the default browser again

Comment: try to reinstall Chrome, set the default browser again, see if it works.

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome that still happens, f***ing Google does not give you an option to clear the history and setting prior to uninstalling it :(

Answer (score 0):

Make a .bat file and put this in it:

```
C:
cd \Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
start chrome.exe -no-default-browser-check
```

Replace your Chrome shortcuts with shortcuts to the .bat file.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are http://superuser.com/users/671884/sevencardz and http://superuser.com/users/671887/user2097210.  You’ll then be able to [edit] your answer and post comments on it.